# Login using arduino and RFID

Tags: arch-linux, login, arduino

I have been thinking about this for a while. How would I go about being able to log in using an Arduino and RFID card reader?

Hardware:
Arduino UNO, Card reader:
RFID-RC522

OS:
Arch Linux

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options:

1. Write firmware for the Arduino that makes it behave like an existing USB smart card reader that is supported by PCSC and PAM
2. Write a custom PAM module to interface with custom firmware for the arduino to do the authentication.

Of the 2 options 1 is the one most likely (but still very unlikely) to end up even remotely secure, but is going to be a LOT of work.

Option 2 is also going to be a LOT of work, but the odds of you making a mistake that is going to lead to security vulnerabilities are likely to be much higher.

Unless you are just looking for a project I suggest spending £15-£50 on Amazon and just buying a dedicated pre-supported USB NFC/RFID card reader. Then follow these instructions: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Smartcards